# Woocommerce product description length characters

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I added the following code to my functions.php file to add a short product description under the thumbnails on my shop page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2);
if (!function_exists('lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt'))
{
function lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt()
{
$content_length = 20;
global $post;
$content = $post->post_excerpt;
$wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $content_length + 1);
if(count($wordarray) > $content_length) :
array_pop($wordarray);
array_push($wordarray, '...');
$content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
$content = force_balance_tags($content);
endif;
echo "<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>";
}
}
```

As you can see [here](http://lostgrok.com) on my website, the descriptions are there, but the length is based on words. Is there anyway I can make the content length of my descriptions based on characters rather than words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `substr()` method:
e.g.

```
$content = substr($content, 0, 20);
```

Where `20` is the amount of characters you want returned.

Code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2);
if (!function_exists('lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt'))
{
function lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt()
{
$content_length = 20;
global $post;
$content = $post->post_excerpt;
$wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $content_length + 1);
if(count($wordarray) > $content_length) :
array_pop($wordarray);
array_push($wordarray, '...');
$content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
$content = force_balance_tags($content);
$content = substr($content, 0, 20);

endif;
echo "<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>";
}
}
```

Comment: Awesome that worked great! Now as you can see by my [http://lostgrok.com](site) that the description is sandwiched between the price and buttons. How can I make the description on top like I had before? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Adding a `clear:both;` to the paragraph tag in the `excerpt` span should fix that.

Comment: great thank you! That definitely fixed the sandwich, how can I make it so the text displays above price and button? When I change the hook from (35,2) to (5,2) it pushes the desc above, but takes on the styling of the title. Hopefully this makes sense.. [see problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065132/woocommerce-product-description-shop-page-format)