# Woocommerce product description shop page format

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have successfully added the a short product description to my shop page, but would like it displayed below the thumbnail, rather than below the price and button.

I can accomplish this by reordering my hooks, but when I do this, the description turns bold and takes on the characteristics of the product title.

See difference below
[image]

Does anyone know how I can make it so the text displays above the price and button, but isn't bold and a link?

See my functions.php code..

```
/** Add buy it now to shop page **/

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

/** Add excerpt below thumbnail **/

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2);
if (!function_exists('lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt'))
{
function lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt()
{
$content_length = 20;
global $post;
$content = $post->post_excerpt;
$wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $content_length + 1);
if(count($wordarray) > $content_length) :
array_pop($wordarray);
array_push($wordarray, '...');
$content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
$content = force_balance_tags($content);
$content = substr($content, 0, 140);

endif;
echo "<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>";
}
}
```

Comment: have you got a link? a quick answer regarding re-ordering the hooks is that one of the hooks is adding a div with the bold style. to see what the code is save $esc_content= esc_html($content); and echo it out. do this both times and you will see what the difference in html mark up is and then you can find which element is causing the bold text to appear.

Comment: We probably would need to see the code of the layout page to really help. The bold on the excerpt is like that because there is a `font-weight:bold` on the `a` style/

Comment: Here is a [link](http://lostgrok.com) to my website, any help would be greatly appreciated. @Howlin the font isn't just bold, it also does not show up as text, I can't highlight or copy the text. Does that make sense?